# If I were you I would tell them it was or is true?

Tags: tense, subjunctives

> If I were you, I would tell them **(that it is not true.)**

The bracket portion should it be in "Past" or "Present"? I am confused because we are using "Past" for the rest of the sentence.

> If I were you, I would tell them that (it was not true.)

Comment: What is "it" and when was it?

Comment: @user3169 - I presumed the "it" refers to some rumor or something.

Answer (score 3):

The two parts of the sentence are independent; the choice of "is" or "was" depends entirely on the tense of what "it" is referring to.  You could actually argue about whether "were" should better be "was".

The first part of the sentence means either "If I was in your place" or even literally "If I had been born you".  The sense of that condition already existing means that the "transition" of who is who already took place, so that part of the sentence is past tense.

"I would tell them" means that telling hasn't happened yet.  Which brings us to what needs to be told.

The "what" that needs to be told is whatever it is.  If "what" refers to something in the past, it would be "that it **was** not true".  If it refers to something where the present condition of truthfulness is what's relevant, it would be "that it **is** not true".  For that matter, it could be about something for which the relevance of truthfulness refers to a future time, in which case you could say, "that it **will** not **be** true".

Comment: Yes, the implication of "it was not true" is that it may be true now. If, however, it "is not true", there is no debate, it remains untrue.

Answer (score -1):

The majority of the time, "it is not true" would be used however, the other form is uncommonly used as a literary device in literature by Authors with peculiar writing styles.

Essentially, you use "it is not true" in all situations unless you are an author trying to make your writing sound a bit more complex.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand could you please ellaborate?

Comment: This is not correct. This is not a matter of complexity, it's a matter of the status of the truthfulness.

Answer (score -1):

Both are fine and both mean the same thing.  Some people prescribe to align the tense since the past subjunctive is almost identical to the past tense, but it's a matter of style above.  I have said it both ways and I've read up on it before.  It can be both and it means the same thing.